# Arch Linux: pacman cannot be upgraded because pacman version is too high?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

This seems a bit like an  April Fools' joke, but this is what I was greeted with this morning, when trying to bring my Arch up to date:

```
:: The following packages should be upgraded first :
    pacman
:: Do you want to cancel the current operation
:: and upgrade these packages now? [Y/n] 

resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: package-query: requires pacman<3.5
```

So what, should I downgrade my pacman before I'm allowed to upgrade it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What this error actually says, is that the version of `package-query` that's installed depends on a lower version of `pacman` than the one you're trying to upgrade to.
This can be solved by running `pacman -Rs yaourt; pacman -Syu;` and then rebuilding `yaourt` and `package-query`.

Comment: Removing yaourt alone didn't remove package-query for me, so I ran pacman -Rs package-query which allowed me to to do a pacman -Syu.

Answer (score 0):

[Go here](http://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/) and re-generate a current server list and then copy it.

I actually pasted the new server list at bottom and commented out the existing ones. I am new at this but can help if you need it.

You can also save your old mirrorlist as a backup and create a new one. I had the same problem trying to get pacman to upgrade to 3.5 to install some software that required it. The mirrorlist is located at /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

Comment: `package-query` is not in the official repositories: changing the mirror list won't make any difference. As oKtosiTe said, the OP needs to uninstall `package-query`, update `pacman` and then rebuild the AUR package.